# How to create pivot table entries for all of the rows available in two separate tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need help to create pivot table entries for all of the rows available in two separate tables, basically, I have two separate tables as `services` and `plans` as below

1. plans table

| id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | plan one | description for plan one |
| 2 | plan two | description for plan two |

2. services table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | service one |
| 2 | services two |

and a pivot table `service_plan` where I am storing the Id of the plan and service with an extra column to store the price as below.

| id | service_id | plan_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 200 |

Now I just want a SQL query to assign all the services with all the available plans with a dummy price in it, so the `service_plan` table will look something like this

| id | service_id | plan_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 200 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 200 |

any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That looks more like a `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: okay - can you provide me with an example query, please.

Comment: Why don't you try this first `SELECT * FROM services CROSS JOIN plans ORDER BY service.id, plan.id;` and see what kind of result will you get.. and how far is it from your expected output.

Comment: it's only going to give me the result from the plans and services table but I want a query to create new records with all the services and plans in the `service_plan` table with a dummy price.

Comment: Well, if you do `SELECT services.id AS service_id, plans.id AS plans_id ..` that should give you the same result in your `service_plan` columns for `services_id` and `plans_id`, right? So, how do you populate the rest of the columns like in your `service_plan` table? Especially _dummy price_ , where do you get that from?

Comment: it'll be changed from the front end manually - for now, I just need a dummy price and there are more data in the service_plan table some of them are null and some of them have a default value, so I need that table anyhow and need a query to create records in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question i think this is the simplest query you can run to get your desired result.

```
insert into service_plan (service_id, plan_id, price) select s.id, p.id, 200 from services as s cross join plans as p
```

Answer (score 1):

why the resistance to a cross join?

```
drop table if exists PLANS,SERVICES,SERVICE_PLAN;

create table plans
(id int,name varchar(100),  description varchar(100));
insert into plans values
(1, 'plan one'  ,'description for plan one'),
(2, 'plan two'  ,'description for plan two');

create table services
(id int, name varchar(20));
insert into services values
(1  ,'service one'),
(2  ,'services two');

create table service_plan
(id int auto_increment primary key, service_id int, plan_id int, price int not null default 200);

insert into service_plan(service_id,plan_id) 
select s.id,p.id
        from plans p
cross join services s
order by s.id,p.id;

select * from service_plan;

+----+------------+---------+-------+
| id | service_id | plan_id | price |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |       1 |   200 |
|  2 |          1 |       2 |   200 |
|  3 |          2 |       1 |   200 |
|  4 |          2 |       2 |   200 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```